# Local development configuration to test web app before deploy to pythonanywhere

Tags: uwsgi, pythonanywhere

What local development configuration is suggested for testing python web apps before deploying to `pythonanywhere`?

May be some XAMPP/LAMP analogue for uWSGI is exist?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In a dev setting you can just use uWSGI as your app and web server, or you can use one of the many Python WSGI servers.